# function(data:Object) as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

How can I get the data from this function using AS3? Or at least how to properly convert it to AS3?

Original **AS-2** Class A was :

```
mc.btn.onRollOut = function(data)
{
    dispatchEvent({type: "itemRollOut", target: _parent.data});
    itemRollOut(data);
}

public function itemRollOut(data)
{

}
```

So I tried to convert it like this below : new **AS-3** Class A

```
mc.btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, btnonRollOut);

function btn.btnonRollOut(evt:MouseEvent)
{
itemRollOut(data);
}

public function itemRollOut(data)
{
  // here returns the data in the other class -- > mc.itemRollOut = function(data:Object)
}
```

This Class B shown below calls the data from the itemRollOut in Class A:

```
mc.itemRollOut = function(data:Object)
{
    trace(data + " : " + data.data);
}
```

**What I'm trying to achieve :**
When I itemRollOut my button, I want to pass the data from the result that Class A gives into Class B.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the data" ? Return it from that function ? or get something from the `data` object ? Try to clarify your question please.

Comment: You are asking how to convert AS2 to AS3 but you are showing code that is valid AS3.

Comment: In your converted Class A if `itemRollOut(data);` then the function should be named `itemRollOut` not that `itemRollOver` as you have it now.. Also `btn.btnonRollOut` does not match what the eventListener is watching. Why cant it be function `btnonRollOut`? Anyways your `itemRollOver` funtion does not return anything (see **Paul Steams** answer for example) you need to declare a return type. Google **AS3 fundamentals** for advice (read **Data Types**, **Variables** and **Functions**). Dont just guess, read the manual.

Comment: How can Class B trace the data of Class A when it seems the data in Class A must come from a function in Class B?? . Are you putting this code in different movieClips? Just put all code in one place (either on one timeline layer or in a single Class document) to control everything centrally.

Comment: Thanks @VC.One for the edit. Sorry for the mistakes i wasn't in my pc so i forgot some.. i edit them correctly... This is a custom component (a list) where i add items inside. when i Mouse Over - Out change the background color of the cell -  and shows in a extra balloon what the cell's contains. when i Select the cell shows the cell data in a text Area. The mc.itemRollOut = function(data:Object) refers  to the component public function itemRollOut(data) Class A. I thing what i need is a dispatchEvent with the data inside so the class B can collect the data when the Over - Out - Select occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking you to define a function such as;

```
private function getSquare(nbr:Number):Number
{
    return nbr * nbr;
}
```

which when called like;

```
var nbrOutvalue:Number = getSquare(20);
```

will return 400?

If so the answer is the :Number at the end of the function definition line, which is the data type of the value to return.